# replacing Roman Numerals I-XXX with RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex, roman-numerals

Removing chapter headings in Roman numerals (no more that 30, which are followed by a space and then a colon) I use:

```
str = str.replace(/^((X{0,3})(I{0,1})(V{0,1})(X{0,1})(I){0,3}:\s+?)$/gim, "");
```

Only it seems to be super-slow. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Is this one better: [`^(X{0,3})(I?)(V?)(X?)(I{0,3}):\s+?$`](https://regex101.com/r/eL6dY3/2)? Almost the same, but a bit cleaned up.

Comment: Why are your matches inside parenthesis?

Comment: @hjpotter92 I was ill on capturing group day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/^([IVX]+:\s+?)$/gim
```

That will run a bit quicker, it looks for the roman numeral characters as a character set. Also, your current version will match a line with just a colon on it (no roman numerals).

Comment: This is perhaps not of practical importance, but I think that will also match some non valid combinations of the characters, such as `VV` or `IIIX`.

Comment: @Anders - that's a good note/caveat, this is a solution tuned specifically for the OPs problem and not a general purpose roman numeral matching regex.